# Ubuntu 18.04 crashes to tty1 on install

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I was notified this afternoon of the upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04. se it off downloaded files and left it running while I went out. When I got back it prompted for a few responses. I gave these and restarted the system after install (appeared) to terminate normally. It won't boot to Gnome, instead giving me a CL interface. Anyone any suggestions how to remedy this? I have run dpkg etc to try and fix matters.

Answer (score 0):

ran:

statusctl status gdm

found that gdm while installed was listed as "Inactive (dead)"

tried many things but ended up re-installing gdm3 with

sudo aptitude reinstall gdm3

[note the re-install option doesn't exist in apt-get]

Rebooted (from cold) and it worked.

Hope this helps someone.